# How to pass variable into Django block in url?

Tags: django, django-urls

**Context**

I am trying to loop through a list of objects, then call on the name and id attribute and pass it into the Url block as regex to be captured in the urls.py later.

**Problem**

```html
{%if people_found%} 
   {%for the_people in people_found%}
         <a href="{% url 'Search4Bday:profile' '{{the_people.firstname}}/ {{the_people.id}}' %}">{{the_people.firstname}}</a> 
   {%endfor%} 
{%endif%}
```

**Urls.py**

```html
 app_name = 'Search4Bday'
 urlpatterns= [path("search/profile/<str:firstname>/<int:id>", views.profile, name = "profile")]
```

**Question**

I'm not sure how I can pass the variables into the urls.py file if I can't call on the variable `the_people` with double curly braces. I'm also not sure if this is the correct way to pass in the variables into the regular expression capture portion of the urls.py. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `add` tag of [Django Template Lang](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/language/):

```
{% if people_found %} 
   {% for the_people in people_found %}
         <a href="{% url 'Search4Bday:profile' the_people.firstname|add:"/"|add:the_people.id %}">{{the_people.firstname}}</a> 
   {% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```

edit: I didn't pay attention to urls.py and this will not work as wanted. Instead of adding slashes between variables put them directly. So this should work.

```
{% if people_found %} 
   {% for the_people in people_found %}
         <a href="{% url 'Search4Bday:profile' the_people.firstname the_people.id %}">{{the_people.firstname}}</a> 
   {% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried another method, I could have just done this:

```html
{% if people_found %} 
   {% for the_people in people_found %}
         <a href="{% url 'Search4Bday:profile' the_people.firstname the_people.id %}">{{the_people.firstname}}</a> 
   {% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/language/

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't pay attention at that moment sorry.